# $a,b,c$ are digits. İf $a+2b+3c=40$ then what is the largest value for $a+b+c$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am finding it hard to understand the method and the logic behind this.

I read that we have to give the one with the smallest coefficient the biggest value ,why is this . ?

Comment: we need more constraints, i.e.  $a,b,c \ge 0$  otherwise it is unbounded.

Comment: @DougM  I expect (but am not sure) that by "digits" the OP means $a,b,c\in \{0,1,2,\dots, 9\}$.

Comment: lulu yes that's what I mean

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Rather than quoting what you read, try solving a smaller similar problem. What's the largest value for $a+b$ if $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers such that $a+2b = 5$? Then try to generalize.

Comment: You must have some thoughts.  After all, ignoring the constraint of $a+2b+3c$ the maximum for $a+b+c$ is $27$.  Can you get $27$ here?  What about $26$?  And so on.

Comment: i got $$a+b+c\le 22$$ for $a=9,b=8,c=5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that we have to give the one with the smallest coefficient the biggest value; why is this?

Let's say you are going to market to buy fish.  Some fish cost \$1, some cost \$2, others cost \$3.  You have \$40 and want to buy *the most fish*.  How many of each should you buy?  Clearly you should buy 40 of the one-dollar fish.  You could swap two of the one-dollar fish for one two-dollar fish; that would result in the same amount paid, but would result in one less fish.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have found an optimal triple $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c\in\{0,\ldots,9\}$. 
Note that $a+2b+3c=40$ implies $3c=40-a-2b\ge 40-9-18=13$ and so $c>4$.
Also, $2b=40-a-3c\ge 40-9-27=4$ and so $b\ge 2$.

If $a<8$ in our optimal solution, then (as $b\ge 2$ and so $b-1$ is still a digit), then $(a+2,b-1,c)$ is a valid triple and has larger target sum, contradicting optimality.
We conclude that $a\ge 8$ in any optimal triple.

Similarly, if $b<7$, then $(a,b+3,c-2)$ is an improvement. We conclude that $b\ge 7$.

In particular, $a$  and $b$ are not far apart: $|a-b|\le 2$. then from  $a-b=40-3b-3c=1+3\cdot(13-b-c)$, we conclude that $a-b=1$ and also that $13-b-c=0$. This makes $a+b+c=13+a$, so we certainly want to make $a$ as large as possible, namely $a=9$, leading to  the maximal target sum $a+b+c=13+a=22$, where by the way $b=a-1=8$ and $c=13-b=5$.

Comment: How did you get all the numerical values though?